# removing all the keys with the same value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get a new dictionary by removing all the keys with the same value (keys are differents, values are the same)

For example: Input:

```
dct = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}
```

expected output:

```
 {'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```

key1 and key3 was deleted because they shared same values.

I have no idea about it?

Comment: what is there is 3 times the value ? none of the 3 keys ?

Comment: @azro Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a dictionary based on the values. In this case the values are lists which are not hashable so convert to tuple. The values in the new dictionary are lists to which we append any matching key from the original dictionary. Finally, work through the new dictionary looking for any values where the list length is greater than 1 - i.e., is a duplicate. Then we can remove those keys from the original dictionary.

```
d = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}

control = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    control.setdefault(tuple(v), []).append(k)

for v in control.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        for k in v:
            del d[k]

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a list of counts which holds information about how many times an item is in the dictionary. Then I copy only items which are there once.

```
a = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [1,2,6], "key3": [1,2,3]}

# find how many of each item are there
counts = list(map(lambda x: list(a.values()).count(x), a.values()))
result = {}

#copy only items which are in the list once
for i,item in enumerate(a):
    if counts[i] == 1:
        result[item] = a[item]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

As given by the OP, the simplest solution to the problem:

```
dct = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}

print({k:v for k, v in dct.items() if list(dct.values()).count(v) == 1})
```

Output:

```
{'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```

Comment: Functionally correct but ~25% slower than my proposal

Comment: @OlvinRoght I believe yes the .count() slows things down. However that is intended to be concise rather than efficient here. Both would be a must, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

One loop solution:

```
dict_ = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}

key_lookup = {}
result = {}
for key, value in dict_.items():
    v = tuple(value)
    if v not in key_lookup:
        key_lookup[v] = key
        result[key] = value
    else:
        if key_lookup[v] is not None:
            del result[key_lookup[v]]
            key_lookup[v] = None

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dct = {'key1' : [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}
temp = list(dct.values())

result = {}

for key, value in dct.items():
    for t in temp:
        if temp.count(t) > 1:
            while temp.count(t) > 0:
                temp.remove(t)
        else:
            if t == value:
                result[key] = value

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```